# Bootstrap: I have centered the navbar with custom css, but when I press it. It jumps to one side. I can't figure out why

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I tried to center my navbar-toggler, but only succeeded in centering the navbar-contend with bootstrap. Then I went one step further and centered the navbar-toggler icon with custom css, but now it jumps to the left when I press it. I cant figure out why.

I am

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My resumé</title>


  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anonymous+Pro&family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c4df5125eb.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    #navbar-center {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .card {
      margin: 2vh 1rem;
    }
    
    footer {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      padding-left: 90vw;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  </header>
  <div id="navbar-center">
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <!-- Center the toggler icon -->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary" href="#executive-summary">Executive Summary</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary" href="#technical-skillset">Skillset</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="executive-summary"></div>
  <div id="technical-skillset"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried tinkering of course, google, stack overflow and chat GPT. Last one is useless.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem with the little code you gave, but I was not successful. The navbar never centers and always fills the whole width of the browser window. Please read; [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you. I updated the code, and now it gets a bit extended because I am not really sure where the problem is.

Comment: I copied all of your code and got a mesmerizing background gradient. No NavBar however. I added some items to the Navbar, and they just appear as normal texts in the center and do nothing. No error in the console. I deleted all your CSS, no success. There wasn't [a grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/) so I added it. Still no visible NavBar. Ah, the Bootstrap JS file is missing! Added it. Still not working. Oh I give up. In short: It's still not a minimal reproducible example of your problem. Did you test the code your published in your question at all? You should.

Comment: OK, I will. Please. I am sorry. I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: OK, sorted. I have now replicated and isolated the code that is affected. You need to minimize the viewport to be able to see the toggler.

Comment: Yes, now your example works! I can indeed see the toggle move to the left when I click on it. The cause is that the container, holding the toggle and the dropdown, becomes wider. I added your `justify-content-center` class to the container `<div>` and the problem was solved: In other words the toggle stays in the center.

Comment: It "jumps", because you stuck a `.container-fluid` element into the `. navbar` element. Both the navbar and the container have `display: flex` - meaning, your container is only as wide as its content demands it, to begin with. And when you click the button, you change what that content is - all of a sudden, the collapse element is also there, and that is multiple times wider, than your button. So the container has become wider now, and the div you wrapped around the button - which is _also_ only as wide as the button itself - is left-aligned inside the container.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried targeting it without custom css but couldnt figure it out. Now I even removed custom css. Beautiful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The exact solution is less important than being able to find a solution yourself in the future. I did this by using [the browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools). These are very important tools when making a website. It might seem slightly complex to start with but they can help a lot. It took me less than a minute to see the cause of your problem.

Comment: I am already using developer tools. I just couldn't find the solution. Your advice is still solid. Thanx buddy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the width of your `div.d-flex` I added `.w-100`, and then used `.mx-auto` on the `.navbar-toggler`. That gives you a flexbox with 100% width and a button with auto left & right margins.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My resumé</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anonymous+Pro&family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c4df5125eb.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    #navbar-center {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .card {
      margin: 2vh 1rem;
    }
    
    footer {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      padding-left: 90vw;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  </header>
  <div id="navbar-center">
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="d-flex w-100">
          <!-- Center the toggler icon -->
          <button class="navbar-toggler mx-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary" href="#executive-summary">Executive Summary</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary" href="#technical-skillset">Skillset</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="executive-summary"></div>
  <div id="technical-skillset"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Hey, bootstrap is something...